# Why is the route in apicontroller not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller

I have a controllerclass called  "GebruikersController"

when I use "https://localhost:5001/Gebruikers" I get the right output but when I use "https://localhost:5001/api/GebruikerController/Gebruikers" (how it should work?) I get a blank page. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RESTAPI.Data;
using RESTAPI.Data.Repositories;
using RESTAPI.DTOs;
using RESTAPI.Models;

namespace RESTAPI.Controllers
{
  [ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class GebruikersController : ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly IGebruikerRepository _gebruikerRepository;

    public GebruikersController(IGebruikerRepository context)
    {
            _gebruikerRepository = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Gebruikers
    /// <summary>
    /// Geeft alle gebruikers geordend op achternaam
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>array van gebruikers</returns>
    [HttpGet("/Gebruikers")]
    public IEnumerable<Gebruiker> GetGebruikers()
    {
            return _gebruikerRepository.GetAlleGebruikers().OrderBy(d => d.Achternaam);
    }

    // GET: api/Gebruikers/5
    /// <summary>
    /// Geeft de gebruiker met het gegeven id terug
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">het id van de gebruiker</param>
    /// <returns>De gebruiker</returns>
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<Gebruiker> GetGebruiker(int id)
    {
      Gebruiker gebruiker = _gebruikerRepository.GetBy(id);
      if (gebruiker == null) return NotFound();
      return gebruiker;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use 
`https://localhost:5001/api/Gebruikers/Gebruikers` 
instead of 
`https://localhost:5001/api/GebruikerController/Gebruikers`.

The "*controller*" word is not written in the URL.

Comment: When I use that one I get an error. {"type":"tools.ietf.org/html/… or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|50c831bb-4dab87ead88f6d56.","errors":{"id":["The value 'Gebruikers' is not valid."]}}

Comment: Actually the name of the Controller is GebruikersController with an s, how does https://localhost:5001/api/Gebruikers/Gebruikers work out for you?

Comment: @user2768479 I used that one and then I got an error
{"type":"tools.ietf.org/html/… or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|50c831bb-4dab87ead88f6d56.","errors":{"id":["The value 'Gebruikers' is not valid."]}}

Answer (score 0):

Add a Route attribute on the action. then, both routes will be recognized.

```
[HttpGet("/Gebruikers")]
[Route("Gebruikers")]
public IActionResult GetGebruikers()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

The slash will ignore the route attribute on your controller, so it can only recognize the route: "https://localhost:5001/Gebruikers"